# Missing an important piece in OTP Validation

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs

Below code fragment is a method that validates OTP. Note, the OTP that is sent on SMS is hashed and stored in DB. So we need to hash the otp the user enters for verification to compare with the record in DB for matching.
There is scope for some important improvement here, please ignore the syntax. I can't seem to point it out except the fact that it may be related to some difference in DB time and current Time. Any ideas will be helpful here

```
1. validateOtp(mobileNo, otp) {
2.    const otpThatWasSentRecord = otpRepository.getLastSentOtp(mobileNo);
3.    const otpHash = hashHelper.computeHash(otp);
4.    const currentDatetime = (new Date()).toUtc()

5.    if (otpThatWasSentRecord.expiresAtUtc < currentDatetime || otpHash !== otpThatWasSentRecord.otpHash)
6.           throw BadRequestError('Otp incorrect or expired');

7.    ......
8.}
```

Comment: Is there a question here? I don't see it.